# kendo grid footer/pager broken inside bootstrap tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, grid, kendo-ui

I found that kendo grid has an issue when placed inside a bootstrap tab that is not currently visible. When the tab is made visible, the footer (pager) appears disconnected from the grid.
If the grid is initialized after the tab is shown, everything appears fine. Also, if the datasource is read() from, everything appears fine (snaps into place).
Neither of these may be desirable (I may wish to init on dom ready, or do not wish to read when the tab is selected).

How can I resolve this?

I am answering my own question below, but would be interested in alternate, refined or "more proper" solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is the issue listed here http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/grid-height-issues.aspx the height of the k-grid-content div needs to be recalculated, but only once (as that seems to fix the issue for the particular page view).

This code should resolve the issue:

```
function recalculateGridSize(gridElement) {
    gridElement = $(gridElement);
    var contentHeight = $('.k-grid-content').height();
    var headerHeight = gridElement.find('.k-grid-header').height(),
        pagerHeight = gridElement.find('.k-grid-pager').height();
    contentHeight = contentHeight - (pagerHeight + headerHeight);
    gridElement.find('.k-grid-content').css('height', contentHeight);
};

$('body').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    var currentTabHref = $(e.target).attr('href');
    $($(e.target).attr('href')).find('.k-grid:not([data-recalculated])').each(function() {
        recalculateGridSize(this);
        $(this).attr('data-recalculated', 'true');
    });
});
```

Hope this is helpful.